# pug.compile() cannot find template files (res.render() can)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm writing a small NodeJS/Express app. I set up pug as its template engine:

```
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + "/public/views");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/static'));
```

This works fine when calling a `res.render()` to send HTML responses:

```
app.get('/', function getIndex(req, res){
    res.render('index.pug');
});
```

But when I try to render small components and collect them in a string or an array as response to an AJAX call, I can't get it to work.

```
const pug = require('pug');
const compile = pug.compileFile('option.pug');
```

This always results in `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'option.pug'`. I tried changing the path to the router's perspective (so something like `../../public/views/option.pug`) but this also does not help.

I don't know why the paths are interpreted differently.

How do I refer to this template when using `pug.compileFile`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Pug source code, the passed path is set as the `filename` in the options:

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/926f7c720112cac76cfedb003e25e9f43d3a1767/packages/pug/lib/index.js#L354

This is then passed to `handleTemplateCache` to read the file:

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/926f7c720112cac76cfedb003e25e9f43d3a1767/packages/pug/lib/index.js#L215

So ultimately the path is just being passed to `fs.readFileSync`, which treats relative paths as being relative to the current working directory, `process.cwd()`.

You could generate the appropriate path using something like this:

```
const file = app.get('views') + '/option.pug';
```

It would be better to use `path.join` rather than string concatenation for building paths, https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

```
const path = require('path');
const file = path.join(app.get('views'), 'option.pug');
```

If you don't want to (or can't) use `app.get('views')` you could just build up the absolute path by other means, such as using `__dirname` directly.

Note also that you can pass a callback to `res.render` which will be passed the rendered HTML instead of writing it to the response. That may allow you to avoid calling the template directly in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This works, although I avoided the problem altogether by abstracting this part of my application away.